# Panda :Python - Search a dataFrame by index name , return df and ignore index names that does not exists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a panda Dataframe like the image below. The index col is with string values (index names), not the integer values

How do I pass a list/dic of index names such as [a, d, e, 'invalid_index'] and get back a filtered df with only the valid values that I pass and ignore any invalid indexes. In this case df with only a, d, e and ignore invalid_index

this is what I have right now :

filtered_df = df.loc[['a','d','e']]

the problem with this that if I will get an error if I pass an index name that is not exists in the df

e.g
filtered_df = df.loc[['invalid','d','e']]

How do I get a df with only indexname : d and e?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just check index value in target list

   ```py
   df.loc[[x for x in ['invalid', 'd', 'e'] if x in df.index]]
   ```
2. np.isin calculates element in test_elements, broadcasting over element only. It returns a boolean array so you can use it.

   ```py
   import numpy as np
   df.loc[np.isin(df.index, ['invalid', 'a', 'b'])]
   ```

Comment: Great, thanks Lazyer. Option 1 did not work for me but option 2 works like a charm.